# How to create map keys in a loop?

Tags: go

I do according to the textbook, but there is an error

panic: assignment to entry in nil map (in line `keyval["{x[i]}"] = 0`)

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := [3]string{"aa","bb","cc"}

    var keyval map[string]int

    for i := 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        keyval["{x[i]}"] = 0
    }

    fmt.Println(keyval)
}
```

I tried to use `keyval["x[i]"] = 0` but the effect is the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must first initialize your map:

```
keyval := make(map[string]int)
```

According to [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) blog post:

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices, and so the
>   value of m above is nil; it doesn't point to an initialized map.

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/2JuPS1J7KK

Edit to answer OP's followup. If you're looking to use the strings from your slice as the key to the map, you need to make an additional change:

```
keyval[x[i]] = 0
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/feMSwvbEGS

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for my carelessness. But answer is map[{x[i]}:0] but I expected map[aa:0]

Comment: You have a map of string -> int. Your key is "{x[i]}", since that's the string you provided. If you want to use the string from your slice instead, you need to do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/feMSwvbEGS